# Wpf binding of TextBox inside ElementHost not updating when click on win forms control

Tags: wpf

I have a win forms application on which an WPF UserControl is hosted using ElementHost. When user changes the text of textbox inside WPF user control and click on any Win forms control it does not update the binded property of the ViewModel.

It is not possible to change the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged because for each change in ViewModel I need to add an undo entry. I have read some articles saying that win forms and wpf have their own focus contexts  which are not shared. Anyone has found any workaround for this ?

Thanks
Sameera

Comment: If setting the UpdateSourceTrigger to PropertyChanged solves your problem then it's a focus problem. You should check if the button you are clicking can receive focus and the focus is changed on click.

Comment: If textbox receives lostfocus it properly updates the binding source. But the problems is when I click on a control in win forms side wpf textbox does not receive lost focus event. But win forms control gets the focus.

Comment: I had a similar problem with WPF/MFC application. A simple workaround is to handle the LostKeyboardFocus event of the Texbox and update the binding Source yourself. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I am out of office for two weeks. As soon as I get back I will try this.

Comment: Finally got time to check!. I checked with Snoop for which events it get fired. Seems like none of these events get fired when I click on ToolBar buttons and Ribbon buttons. (I am using DotNetBar controls for toolbar and ribbon bar). However for other common win forms controls LostKeyboardFocus gets fired.